# Are there any affordable, good parametric modeling applications for OS X?

Tags: macos, 3d-modeling, cad

I've been searching with Google and Bing all morning and haven't found anything.  I can't afford a $3000 cad system.  I just want an affordable, hobby-level, parametric modeler.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Alibre Hobby version](http://www.alibre.com/products/hobby/) it is 99 dollars, and has a lot of the [features](http://www.alibre.com/products/hobby/features.asp) of the Pro version.  Since it allows the export you can send what you deign out to rapid prototyping houses.  It is a lot of fun.  Also the parametric stuff that they do is a real life saver if you are designing parts for projects.  Check out the [videos](http://www.alibre.com/training_support/freealibrevideotraining.asp).

Since this has the OSX tag, then you will need to load windows either in a VM or Bootcamp.

If you are a student [Rihno](http://www.rhino3d.com/) is less than 200 bucks.
Also if you absolutely need a mac program, this is a solid modeler but for 2D stuff I use [QCad](http://www.qcad.org/qcad.html).

Comment: Thanks for the PC recommendations.  I've found several parametric modelers for PC (even parametric plug-ins for Blender), but nothing for OS X.  I should qualify that I'd favor a 3D parametric modeler.  Interesting that no business has filled this niche.  It doesn't even have to be terrific, over-the-top, AutoDesk Inventor competitor.

Answer (score 0):

I can warmly recommend [Luxology Modo](http://www.luxology.com/store/modo/). It's still a bit on the pricey side ($995), but that's a great deal less than $3000. I think this is the best "in-between" big-bucks and low budget solutions, where you get the most "bang for the buck."

They also offer a [free 15 day trial, or a $25 day production evaluation license](http://www.luxology.com/trymodo/), where you also get full access to their translators, SDKs, asset sharing sites etc. I encourage you to give it a whirl!

---

**Edit:**

On second thought; this might not be what you're looking for. I missed the word "parametric" in your title - my apologies. I think you'll still be able to use Modo for some "hard-surface-modelling," but it might not be able to offer you that "architectural precision."